# struts 2 checkboxlist doesn't save values

Tags: struts2

jsp content:

```
<s:checkboxlist list="list" name="values"/>
```

action content:

```
public List<Foo> getList() {
   return list;
}

public String[] getValues() {
    return values;
}

public void setValues(String[] values) {
    this.values = values;
}
```

class Foo:

```
private String code;

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public String toString() {
    return code;
}
```

When I put breakpoint at `getValues()` method, I clearly see it's being called with some values there. But that values don't appear to be selected on a page.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try with `value` attribute.

Comment: I tried. Added value attribute `value="values"` doesn't help.

Comment: Add some expression there which checks whether element is in list/array or not.

Comment: I already found the problem. I'll update my post

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I've added

```
<s:checkboxlist list="list" name="values" listKey="code" listValue="code />
```

to jsp and it all started working after that. It generates the same html, but it seems that despite rendering correctly, that properties are required by struts to check what values should be set. And there is no emphasis on that in struts docs.

**EDIT:**

It seems that only this is actually requited for this thing to work:

```
<s:checkboxlist list="list" name="values" listKey="code"/>
```